# Debuggee CPU state in a Visual Studio macro

Tags: visual-studio, envdte, visual-studio-macros

In a Visual Studio macro, can I directly retrieve the CPU state of the debuggee process? It's a vanilla Wintel-32 process. `GetExpression("EAX")` works, but calling it for all registers takes a nontrivial amount of time.

Maybe one can automate the Registers window somehow...